# xcodebuild doesn't build dependencies on Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, dependencies, osx-mountain-lion, xcodebuild, xcode4.5

I'm having a problem with my build server (which is use for automatically building my iOS apps) after upgrading to Mountain Lion and XCode 4.5.
The problem is that the command line utility 'xcodebuild' doesn't build the dependencies of my project anymore.
Basically I have one directory/project containing the sources for my app and one directory/project containing common library code, the latter directory is set via a Source Tree variable in XCode preferences.

My laptop has Lion installed and there it works flawlessly (xcodebuild first builds all the dependencies from the library project before building the app project sources). However, if I copy the two directories to the build server, set the proper source location for the library project and execute xcodebuild, it doesn't build the library dependencies. It picks up the library source dir all right, because the header search path is fine, it just skips building the dependencies. In the XCode GUI it works OK it's just the command line that doesn't work.
XCode versions are the same (Xcode 4.5 Build version 4G182 as printed by xcodebuild -version), the only difference is the OS version.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem until I did

rm ~/Library/Preferences/xcodebuild.plist

See this thread for more

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Mar/msg00040.html

Comment: Thanks! It's actually rm ~/Library/Preferences/xcodebuild.plist but it worked!

Comment: I don't have a `xcodebuild.plist` in my Preferences folder.